# Find child by index jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

jQuery can return last or first child,it works ok.

But I need to get second child.

This construction (get child by index) doesn't work,when get its text:

```
child.parent().parent().children().get(1).text()
```

So, how can i find non-last and non-first child (e.g. second)?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this: (`.eq()`):

```
selection.eq(1).text()
```

Answer (score 8):

Try `eq()` instead of `get()`:

```
child.parent().parent().children().eq(1).text()
```

You can also do it by selector:

```
$("div:eq(1)")
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of my sites, I have:

```
$('#tr_' + intID).find("td").eq(3).html("Hello there!");
```

Essentially, this will get all the `TD` elements from a table `TR` with `id='tr_123'`.

`eq(3)` then gets the (`0`-indexed!) fourth cell of that `TR`, and changes its HTML contents to `Hello there!`.